# Autoconf and ./configure variables

Tags: autoconf, automake

I have a little problem with autoconf, I know that you can use configure.ac to add some defines to configure.h, but is there a way to do something like this:

in one of my headers I have

```
#ifndef SIZE
#define SIZE 4
#endif
```

now I want to have an option that if I invoke

```
./configure
```

it creates makefile and the size is 4, but when someone does

```
./configure --block-size=num
```

the SIZE will be set to num, preferably I want to do this without config.h, I just want him to add something to makefile, so the compilation will be invoked with

```
-DSIZE=num
```

Comment: Another option is just to document the fact users can run `./configure CPPFLAGS=-DSIZE=4`.  And this requires no change in your setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# configure.ac
AC_ARG_WITH([blocksize],
            AS_HELP_STRING([The desired blocksize [[default: 4]]]),
            [blocksize="$withval"], [blocksize=4])
my_CPPFLAGS="-DSIZE=$blocksize"
AC_SUBST([my_CPPFLAGS])
```

Quite simple.

```
# Makefile.am
AM_CPPFLAGS = ${my_CPPFLAGS}
```

Comment: Rather than my_CPPFLAGS, you can assign AM_CPPFLAGS in configure.ac (and AC_SUBST([AM_CPPFLAGS])) and make no modifications to Makefile.am